# Full Outer Join NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

I am trying to do a full outer join in fluent nhibernate, but I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax to get this method to work.

I have tried join alias as well as projections, but neither seem to be working.

For example, if I have two objects (A and B), I need to get all of object A, and all of Object B, but they might not always have a full relation. Object A has a relation to object B, but I might have object B that is not related to object A at all, and I might have objects A that don't have any of object B.

```
public class objectA{
  public virtual int? ID {get; set; }
  public virtual string someData {get; set;}
  public virtual ObjectB objB {get; set;}
}

public class objectB{
  public virtual int ID_B {get; set;}
  public virtual bool boolVale {get; get;}
  public virtual int? someInt {get; set;}
}
```

My mappings for them would look like this:

```
public objectA_Map(){

  Table("objectA_Table"); 
  Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID"); 
  Map(x=> x.someData).Column("someData");
  References(x => x.objB).Column("fkToB");
}

public objectB_Map(){
    Table("objectB_Table"); 
    Id (x => x.ID_B).Column("ID"); 
    Map(x =>x.boolValue).Column("Deleted"); 
    Map(x => x.someInt).Column("Number"); 
}
```

Again, I need each row of the resulting query to contain my A_ID, someData, ID_B, boolValue, for all objects, even if B doesn't have an A and all A's even if there is no B.

Any insight would be much help.

The SQL I am trying to generate should look something like this:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.someData, B.ID AS BID, B.DELETED, B.Number
FROM objectA_Table A 
FULL OUTER JOIN objectB_Table B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: This should be possible. Could you show the SQL you're trying to generate?

Comment: I have updated the original post to now include a sample of the SQL I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably won't be able to select out full entities like this, but you could build a list of DTOs from your query using QueryOver:

```
IList<DTO> result = session.QueryOver<A>(() => aAlias)
    .Full.JoinQueryOver(p => p.B, () => bAlias)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(() => aAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.AId)
        .Select(() => aAlias.SomeData).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.SomeData)
        .Select(() => bAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.BId)
        .Select(() => bAlias.Deleted).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.Deleted)
        .Select(() => bAlias.Number).WithAlias(() => resultAlias.Number))
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<DTO>())
    .List<DTO>();
```

This will generate the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    this_.Id         as y0_,
    this_.SomeData   as y1_,
    bAlia1_.Id       as y2_,
    bAlia1_.Deleted  as y3_,
    bAlia1_.Number   as y4_
FROM   
    [A] this_
    full outer join [B] bAlia1_ on this_.Id = bAlia1_.aId
```

With DTO looking like this:

```
public class DTO
{
    public Guid AId { get; set; }

    public string SomeData { get; set; }

    public Guid BId { get; set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```